# I'm looking for user experience guidelines for orientation of mobile apps

Tags: mobile, screen-orientation

I presume that re-orientating a mobile device should show more or less the same information but hypothetically it could change the screen completely. For example, a games programmer could choose to combine two games selected by orientation. This feels wrong to me but I would like some published guidelines specifically concerning orientation as well as your opinions please.

Comment: Good question but there an SE site better suited for UX posts: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this document: [Apple User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf)

Of course, it's apple specific to their requirements for app acceptance, but I think it's very insightful to what a user expects from orientation changes and what you should try to provide and can be useful to any mobile developer.

**Edit: start at the bottom of page 58 :) This thing's real long.**

Comment: This doesn't mention changing mode completely.

Comment: "Avoid gratuitous changes in layout. As much as possible, provide a consistent experience in all orientations. A comparable experience in all orientations allows people to maintain their usage patterns when they rotate the device."Now, entirely changing game modes as you mention would be an exception, but perhaps the lack of documentation on it is a hint on how "wrong" people feel that it is, as you do. I could see it being a cool idea though, changing between a couple simple arcade games or something. I think you'll have a tough time finding guidelines specific to that idea though. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I appreciate your help. I'm torn between it being a cool idea and being unexpected and wrong.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. But since you wouldn't want to accidentally change from one game to another while playing one by switching orientation, I would say your choice by orientation would only happen at the home screen where you could clearly state in some small text "rotate to play..." or something, which would switch to the other game's menu. Just some thoughts.